# Error trying to access other tenant users calendars, using MS Graph API

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, passport.js, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a node.js/express application.
I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to fetch users' Calendars [read-only].

OAuth2 library for login:  [passport-microsoft](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-microsoft) npm module.

I followed the following steps in the Azure Portal:

1. Go to Active Directory
2. Click on App Registrations in the left pane
3. Click on New Registration and create an app
4. Go to the new app
5. Click on Authentication in the left panel and add redirect URI's
6. Go to API Permissions and enable the following :

   a. Delegated: Calendars.Read, Calendars.Read.Shared, profile
7. Provide Admin Consent for all the permissions that require it.

However, only users who belong to my azure organisation, under which I have registered my web application, are able to login.

Other organisation users are unable to login. I get the following error message:

```js
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]  InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at /srv/node_modules/passport-microsoft/lib/strategy.js:86:29
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at passBackControl (/srv/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
2019-11-11 10:16:35 default[20191109t101750]      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

You can read my previous question for reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679990/compacttoken-parsing-failed-with-error-code-80049217-when-using-passport-librar/58689974#58689974)

Comment: Your app needs to allow other organizations to log in by making it multi-tenant.

Comment: I have made it multi-tenant, however, still no success

Comment: Please add more details about the error message you got.

Comment: I have added the steps I am following, and the error message I am getting. Please let me know if I can provide more information

Comment: Also. The application has been registered as Multi-Tenant from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering the app as Multi-Tenant and doing the admin consent for your own tenant is not enough.

You need to do the admin consent for this Multi-Tenant Azure AD app against the other tenants.

To grant admin consent through a URL request:

Construct a request to `login.microsoftonline.com` with your app configurations and append on `&prompt=admin_consent`.

This URL will look like: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id of other tenant>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect URI>&nonce=1234&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&prompt=admin_consent`

After signing in with admin credentials of other tenant, the app has been granted consent for all users in that tenant.

Comment: So this process will have to be done for all tenants that want to use this application ?
Once this app goes to production, and we have a new tenant as a user, what's a good way to implement this ? The admin consent, that is

Comment: Also, the application will be hosted on GCP, just using the AD App Registration for using Microsoft Graph API

Comment: Yes. You need to do admin consent for each other tenant who wants to use your Azure AD app. You can generate the request in your web app, and make the admin of the new tenant to log in to do the admin consent when they begin.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the advice Allen. I'll try this out today and update here.

Comment: I need to implement this in a way, where I do not need an Admin approval before other users can start accessing the product. Just like Google Login

Comment: What you want to achieve is against the Azure AD authentication strategy. Before users from your own tenant can access the data, you need to do the admin consent on Azure portal (by clicking on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}"). How can other tenants' users accessing the data without the admin consent for their tenants? Even if the Azure AD app is registered in their own tenant, they will need to do admin consent.

Comment: Hmm. Yes. That's a valid point. But then how are apps like Calendly providing office365/outlook logins without needing an admin consent ? Are they using a different mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

The older version of *admin consent* was not working for me.

Now URL for admin consent looks like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

This worked for me well.
The new version is described in [Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent)